# How to tell if there's no default file extension association on OS post-Windows XP?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-shell, windows-explorer

Going back to the days of Windows XP one could use the following code to tell if there's no file association existed for an extension:

```
TCHAR buffPath[MAX_PATH] = {0};
DWORD dwszBuffPath = MAX_PATH;

HRESULT hR = ::AssocQueryString(
    ASSOCF_NOFIXUPS | ASSOCF_VERIFY, 
    ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE,
    _T(".weirdassextension"),
    NULL,
    buffPath,
    &dwszBuffPath);

if(hR != S_OK &&
    hR != E_POINTER)
{
    //Association does not exist
}
```

But since Windows 8, the `AssocQueryString` API returns `S_OK` and `buffPath` is set to something like `C:\WINDOWS\system32\OpenWith.exe` if it doesn't find anything.

Is there a better way now to determine that file extension has no Shell association?

PS. I do not want to just compare the file name to `OpenWith.exe`. What if there's a legit executable called just that... There must be a better way.

Comment: Checking for `OpenWith.exe` is the only option. You asked Windows to find an app that handles the requested file, and that is exactly what it is doing. It is fairly easy to check if the returned path is under the Windows folder versus somewhere else, so you can ignore Windows' version of `OpenWith.exe` and accept everyone else's.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Well... except that on Win7 it returns `C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll` and on XP it returns an empty string... and that's as far as I checked. It may be doing something else on other OS's.

Answer (score 3):

I think I got it. The trick was to use the correct flags. This seems to work from XP and up:

```
WCHAR wbuffPath[MAX_PATH] = {0};
DWORD dwszBuffPath = MAX_PATH;
HRESULT hR = ::AssocQueryStringW(ASSOCF_INIT_IGNOREUNKNOWN, 
    ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE,
    L".weirdassextension",
    NULL,
    wbuffPath,
    &dwszBuffPath);

if(hR == 0x80070483)   // HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_NO_ASSOCIATION)
{
    //The association is missing
}
```

There's one other trick there, that took me some time to figure out -- DO NOT use `AssocQueryStringA()`. The shim for `AssocQueryStringA()` that converts its passed string parameters to Unicode has a bug in XP (and [evidently in Vista](https://web.archive.org/web/20130126064240/http://www.logaans-site.co.uk/2011/03/26/assocquerystring-ansi-version-does-not-work-in-xp-or-vista/) as well) that will make that API fail on those OS. So, if you do your own ANSI-to-Unicode conversion and call `AssocQueryStringW()` the problem will go away (Evidently 14 years is not enough time for Microsoft to fix that bug?).

Comment: Are you *really* sure you only want to check for that specific error-code, instead of simply "an error"?

Comment: @Deduplicator: You might have a point. Although that API may fail under so many "unrelated" circumstances, such as: access denied, the buffer passed is not long enough, just to name a few. And who knows how MS will change it in the future to behave in the ways that we cannot envision now. That is why I chose to limit it just to that one error...

Comment: Just FYI, `0x80070483` is `ERROR_NO_ASSOCIATION` passed through `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32()`.

Comment: @c00000fd: Your "piece of garbage" comment was not appropriate.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I thought it's a SKU name for Vista?

Comment: @c00000fd: `0x80070483` is not `ERROR_NO_ASSOCIATION` by itself (which is 1155), it is the result of calling `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_NO_ASSOCIATION)`. If you want to check if the `HRESULT` is `ERROR_NO_ASSOCIATION` specifically then use `if ((HRESULT_FACILITY(hR) == FACILITY_WIN32) && (HRESULT_CODE(hR) == ERROR_NO_ASSOCIATION))` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up on AssocQueryStringA being broken on XP.  Still using some XP instances and couldn't figure out why it wasn't working.