# Trying to get default web browser path fails on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-shell, windows-explorer

I'm doing the following in my app's installer (note that the installer for this project is just a Windows executable (`setup.exe`) and not an MSI.)

First I needed to check if there're file associations for `.htm` and `.html` file types. I [did so already](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35249903/843732). And then if there's no association I needed to add them to be opened by a web browser.

To make a lesser of an impact on a user's system, I thought to go with the user's default web browser. The question is how to find its path?

So I was doing this:

```
//Get default web browser path
WCHAR wbuffPath[MAX_PATH] = {0};
DWORD dwszBuffPath = MAX_PATH;
::AssocQueryStringW(0, ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE, L"http", L"open", wbuffPath, &dwszBuffPath);
```

which seems to work, except when I run it on Windows 10 I get this path (when default is the Edge browser):

> C:\WINDOWS\system32\LaunchWinApp.exe

So how do I get the reset of the parameters to start it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `ASSOCSTR_COMMAND` instead of `ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE`.  By using `ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE`, you are asking for *just* the executable by itself, which is exactly what you are getting back.  `ASSOCSTR_COMMAND` should give you the whole command line for the executable.

Comment: Hah. Interesting. If I do that, it simply gives me `"C:\WINDOWS\system32\LaunchWinApp.exe" "%1"`. That's how they do it in Windows 10. Pretty neat! Thanks.