# Open URL in default browser as a window not a tab in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, url, browser

[`Qt.openUrlExternally`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#openUrlExternally-method) opens an URL in a tab in the default browser if the browser is already open. Is there any way to force this URL to be open in a new window rather than a tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each browser will handle the 'new window' option in a different way, so it will depend absolutely on the user's configuration. If you have information about the browser you may invoke it manually with the corresponding arguments, for example Chrome:

```
system("start chrome /new-window www.your_url.info");
```

To query the default browser you can use the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258970/trying-to-get-default-web-browser-path-fails-on-windows-10).

**EDIT**

This solution is Windows only, but similar actions can be taken for other OSs.